# Is $\text{d}^{\dagger}\text{d}$ or $\text{d}\text{d}^{\dagger}$ by itself a valid operator?

Tags: differential-geometry, laplacian, exterior-derivative

If I simply consider just one of the combinations $\text{d}^{\dagger}\text{d}$ or $\text{d}\text{d}^{\dagger}$ both of them take from $\Omega^r(M)\to \Omega^r(M)$ for some manifold $M$. But do they make sense as operators individually or do they only make sense when they come together as the Laplacian $\Delta = \text{d}^{\dagger}\text{d} + \text{d}\text{d}^{\dagger}$? I have not yet seen them play any role individually in any literature as such, hence, my query. Can anyone point out any application of these individual operators in the literature?

Comment: Where did you find your formula for the Laplacian? The Laplacian is given by $$\Delta=d^*d=-g^{ij}(\partial_i\partial_j-\Gamma^k{}_{ij}\partial_k).$$So there you have another application.

Comment: @Filippo I got it from Nakahara.

Comment: Oh the definitions are equivalent because $d^*= 0$ on $\Omega^0(M)$ :)

Comment: @Filipo That is correct.

Comment: Btw it can be shown that the square of a Dirac operator is always a generalized Laplacian, see proposition 3.38 in Heat Kernels and Dirac Operators, so$$\Delta:=(d+d^*)^2:\Omega(M)\to\Omega(M)$$ is indeed a Laplacian. I wasn't aware of the fact that $\Delta$ maps $\Omega^k(M)$ to $\Omega^k(M)$ and that the restriction to $\Omega^0(M)$ is the usual Laplace Beltrami operator, so that is a nice insight, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $M$ be a Riemannian manifold, then the exterior differential $\mathrm d$ and its adjoint $\mathrm{d}^*$ are both $\mathbb R$-vector space endomorphisms on $\Omega(M)$ - i.e. elements of $\mathrm{End}_{\mathbb{R}}(\Omega(M))$ - and hence the compositions $\mathrm{d}^*\mathrm{d}$ and $\mathrm{d}\mathrm{d}^*$ are both well-defined linear operators. See below for the definition of the adjoint and some references.

---

Let $M$ be a Riemannian manifold, then we can define $\mathrm{d^*}\in\mathrm{End}_{\mathbb{R}}(\Omega(M))$ to be the adjoint of $\mathrm{d}$, i.e. the unique operator such that
$$\int_M\langle \mathrm d\alpha,\beta\rangle(x)|\mathrm dx|=\int_M\langle \alpha,\mathrm d^*\beta\rangle(x)|\mathrm dx|$$
for all $\alpha,\beta\in\Omega_0(M)$, where $\Omega_0(M)\subseteq\Omega(M)$ is the space of compactly supported differential forms and $x\mapsto|\mathrm dx|$ is the Riemannian density. See page 68 in [Heat Kernels and Dirac Operators](https://link.springer.com/book/9783540200628). Note that if $M$ is oriented, then $\mathrm d^*$ can be equivalently defined in terms of the Hodge star operator, see Definition 7.2.9 and Theorem 7.2.10 in [Mathematical Gauge Theory](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-319-68439-0). (In the second reference $\mathrm d^*$ is called the codifferential.)

Comment: Sorry, when I said individually I meant $dd^\dagger$ or $d^\dagger d$ individually. Do these operators have any applications?

Comment: @Dr.user44690 I think that on $\Omega^2(M)$ we have that $d^*=*d*$ for a Minkowski space, so the Maxwell equations $*d*dA=J$ are equivalent to $d^\dagger dA=J$. Apart from that I think that we are rather interested in $d+d^*$, which is a Dirac operator on the canonical Clifford module $C(M)\times\Lambda(TM^*)\to\Lambda(TM^*)$.

Comment: Hmmmmm. I see now. Thanks.

Comment: Can you give a reference for your statement about canonical Clifford Module?

Comment: @Dr.user44690 See Proposition 3.53 in my first reference.

Comment: The proposition tells you even more: Not only is $d+d^*$ a Dirac operator, but it is the Dirac Operator associated to a Clifford connection.